# Tag creation suggestion

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to ask a question about teaching Blender but can't find a suitable tag. Could we have something like learning, training, or any other that would seem relevant to the tag creator (I don't have that privilege).

***[Edit]***

So if answers must absolutely be objective, I see how this could be a problem. I'm seeking help on how to teach Blender (namely I have a one-day course to prepare and I'd like to seek the community's help on what's the most important part to teach) and there may not be one right answer to that question. I figured tutorial makers would be interested in asking advice on methods, content, etc.
In any case thank you for considering my request.

Comment: What's an example question you would ask? Also what kind of response would you expect? Be as specific and thorough as possible and feel free to edit your original post.

Answer (score 3):

Such a tag would be too general since in a sense every post and answer combination is basically teaching Blender. I know that's not *exactly* the same but we do have a scope and try to stick to that. Also any such question would probably be deemed open ended and subject to opinion. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

I would instead recommend breaking down your question into an actual subject matter then take what you will from that and apply it in whatever way you want after. For example if you want to say teach about modifiers, form a question around that.

*Don't treat this answer as law however. I don't quite know the nature of your intentions so leaving a catch-all as to what it reads like and if you disagree a discussion can ensue.*